# Selenium: Clicking on Image which calls javascript function

Tags: selenium

I need to click an image in my application which reloads the page. I wrote a selenium code to click that image which is passed but the page has not been loaded. The following is location on that image.

```
<img onmousedown="doSubmitFrom()" src="/arrow_left.png" class="left" style="vertical-align: bottom; padding: 0pt 5px 7px 0pt;">
```

Why the page is not reloads even after the image has been clicked? It seems clicking the image calls function called doSubmitFrom.

Comment: Can you post the Selenium code which clicks on this element? Have you tried it manually and does the page reload then?

Comment: thnks for the concern.. i've used this mouseDownAt and mouseUpAt.. its working fine now..

Answer (score 0):

You should fire event on this element after clicking.

Depending on version and bindings you use it may change. Assuming use Selenium RC, in Ruby it'll be

```rb
@selenium.click("css=image.left")
@selenium.fire_event("css=image.left", "mousedown")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with WebDriver. There are many reasons to upgrade to it.

If it doenst works with Webdriver edit your way you declare your ELement > By.X

Comment: By the way, I sometimes experienced that it helped sending a command two times in selenium 1. (especially in opera)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

Get the Object Locator of the Image
So From the Given DOM we can derive the CSS Selector

css=img[onmousedown='doSubmitFrom()']

Step 2:

Click on the Image

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[onmousedown='doSubmitFrom()']")).click();